# Image Processing using Processing

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, processing

-----------------CORRECTED VERSION-----------

I am currently working on a project using Processing. I need to do image processing inside my project, initially I thought of using opencv. But unfortunately I found out that opencv for Processing is not the complete version of the original one. 
How can I start doing image processing using Processing? I found that since processing is a wrapper of java, java language is accepted. Can I use JavaCV inside processing? If so, how?
Here is the sample code:-

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
PImage imgBack, rightSection, leftSection;
PImage img;

void setup(){
  imgBack=loadImage("tk100backback.jpg");
  leftSection=imgBack.get(0,0,14,200);
  rightSection=imgBack.get(438,0,32,200);
  img=createImage(46,200,RGB);
  img.set(0,0,rightSection);
  img.set(32,0,leftSection);
  size(46,200);
  Mat src= Highgui.imread(img.toString());
  Mat tmp=Highgui.imread("templateStarMatching.jpg");
  int result_cols=src.cols()-tmp.cols()+1;
  int result_rows=src.rows()-tmp.rows()+1;
  Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
  Imgproc.matchTemplate(src, tmp, result, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);

  MatOfPoint minLoc = new MatOfPoint();
  MatOfPoint maxLoc = new MatOfPoint();
  MinMaxLocResult mrec=new MinMaxLocResult();
  mrec=Core.minMaxLoc(result,null);

  System.out.println(mrec.minVal);
  System.out.println(mrec.maxVal);

  Point point = new Point(mrec.maxLoc.x+tmp.width(), mrec.maxLoc.y+tmp.height());
 // cvRectangle(src, maxLoc, point, CvScalar.WHITE, 2, 8, 0);//Draw a Rectangle for Matched Region

}
void draw(){
  image(img,0,0);
}
```

It is giving me error continuously that Core doesn't exist and Highgui not properly installed, but they are properly installed

Comment: If you're in Java mode in Processing, you can use any Java library inside your sketch. What have you tried?

Comment: but what about the java classes?

Comment: What about them? I'm really not sure what your question is. You can use Java from Processing, and you can use Processing from Java.

Comment: Perhaps you could specify the kind o image processing you want to do. Processing it self can handle a lot without any libraries...

Comment: About using libraries, read: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library at the bottom are instruction for non Processing libraries.

Comment: A note on "I found out that opencv for Processing is not the complete version of the original one": this implies you already tried using it, and discovered that specific bits you needed don't do what you want. Where is your code that demonstrates this? As long as opencv has the functions you need, why pass it over? And if you did try it but you're missing functions, perhaps people can recommend how to specifically solve the problem of just those functions missing. In this case, show you've done your research by showing code that reached its limit.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans here is the code in the revised question

Comment: handy. can you please add the errors as they are generated by java, too, instead of paraphrasing them?

Comment: It is saying opencv.core.Core is not installed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) with OpenCV? It sounds like your errors are with the install of OpenCV, not your code.

**OpenCV Issues**
1. Did you install OpenCV previously? It can cause issues with the Processing version.
2. If not, try reducing your code down until you reach the line that first causes an error. If it's on the import statements, you know it's an OpenCV install issue.
3. You don't list your OS, but if you're on a Mac you can follow my [detailed instructions for installing it](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2013/08/22/update-installing-opencv-on-mac-mountain-lion/).

**Can I Do It With Another Library?**
Yes, see some of the comments to your question. But the specific process I think you are trying to do will be difficult. I think you're better off getting OpenCV working.

Answer (score 0):

The below code reads an image in Processing and then applies a filter (in this case it pixilates it).

Note that `img.pixels[i]` is a **1 dimensional array**, while pictures are **2d**. A trick to access the 2d location is `img.pixels[r*img.width + c]` where *r* and *c* are the pixels row and column, respectively

```
 // Declaring a variable of type PImage
PImage img;  
void setup() {

  // Make a new instance of a PImage by loading an image file
  ![enter image description here][1]img = loadImage("http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/lifestyle/the-age-of-obama/img/obama-v2/obama09.jpg");
  //img = loadImage("background.jpg");
  size(img.width, img.height);


   int uberPixel = 25;
  for(int row = 0; row < img.height; row+= uberPixel){
    for(int col = 0; col < img.width; col+= uberPixel){
      int colo[] = new int[3];
     int cnt = 0;
     for(int r = row; r <= row + uberPixel; r ++){
       for(int c = col; c <= col +uberPixel; c ++){
          if(r*img.width + c < img.pixels.length){
            colo[0] += red(img.pixels[r*img.width + c]);
            colo[1] += green(img.pixels[r*img.width + c]);
            colo[2] += blue(img.pixels[r*img.width + c]);
            cnt++;
          }
       }
     }
     //average color
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
       colo[i] /= cnt;
     }

     //change pixel
     for(int r = row; r <= row + uberPixel; r ++){
       for(int c = col; c <= col +uberPixel; c ++){
         if(r*img.width + c < img.pixels.length){
           img.pixels[r*img.width+c] = color(colo[0],colo[1],colo[2]);
         } 
       }
     }

    }
  }
  image(img,0,0);
}

void draw() {
  image(img,0,0);
}
```

## Result:

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example to use `javacv` in Processing:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;

void setup ()
{
    size( 256, 256 );

    String fn = sketchPath("data/lena.jpg");
    IplImage ip= cvLoadImage(fn);
    if ( ip != null ) 
    {
        cvSmooth( ip, ip, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3 );

        PImage im = ipToPImage(ip);
        image( im, 0, 0 );       
        cvReleaseImage(ip);
    }
}
PImage ipToPImage ( IplImage ip ) 
{
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage bImg = ip.getBufferedImage();
    PImage im = new PImage( bImg.getWidth(), bImg.getHeight(), ARGB );
    bImg.getRGB( 0, 0, im.width, im.height, im.pixels, 0, im.width );
    im.updatePixels();
    return im;
}
```